# Recover PreparedStatements from Connection Loss / Session Reconnect?

Tags: java, cassandra

As far as I understand the documentation and what I read, a prepared statement is bound to the session. So the question goes, if I close the connection and recreate it or if the session gets killed (how is that even possible?) one has to recreate all prepared statements right?

What would be the Exception one gets if a PreparedStatement is not managed by the underlying session instance (anymore)?

[Update]

I have created my own simple statement class to represent a prepared statement since I create the statement on creation time just before a session exists. Additionally I use a map to map both on demand and I am ready to go... .

Comment: Are you suggesting that you would use `Connection.prepareStatement()` once, then keep using the same `PreparedStatement` for the remainder of the applications lifetime?

Comment: Correctly As long as the session exist. The documentation states that the driver manages the statement ids for every server one is connected to. So it will save some bandwidth and some cpu cycles. The great idea is thou to configure the consistency level on per statement. Since it is thread save binding the statements is easy.

Comment: The standard way is to recreate the `PreparedStatement` every time you intend to use it (barring batch inserts naturally). The driver is able to cache them, so I would recommend using following the standard pattern for it, instead of attempting to see if the connection has gone bad.

Comment: Here is what Cassandra likes to tell you about this: 12:49:13.273 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-0] WARN  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Re-preparing already prepared query DROP TABLE IF EXISTS XXXX. Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize this was a Cassandra question, not a JDBC question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cassandra Drivers, the standard way is to prepare a statement once and bind variables multiple times before executing.

You can refer to this post: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra

I am sharing a code snippet that you can use. Session validation and preparing statement is something that you need to do at the beginning of your application execution, before starting mutations.

```
    if (session == null) {
        session = CassandraUtils.getInstance().getSession();
        psUsers = session.prepare("INSERT INTO users(xx, yy, zz, tt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        psProducts = session.prepare ("INSERT INTO products(aa, bb, cc, dd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    }
```

From the shared post above:

> Use at most one Session per keyspace, or use a single Session and explicitely specify the keyspace in your queries

For the loss of connection part, driver handles it for you, and of course you can use different kind of reconnection policies: http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/Policies.html